# pgAdmin3 によるリストアができない

Tags: postgresql, database

お力添えをお願いします。
pgAdmin3 によるリストアができず困っています。

【操作手順】
[1] 端末AでpgAdmin3 のオブジェクトブラウザからサーバのデータベースの一つを右クリック「バックアップ」
[2] [1]で生成された watashinodb.backup ファイルを端末Bのローカルフォルダへ移動
[3] 端末BのpgAdmin3 のオブジェクトブラウザからlocalhost のデータベースの一つを右クリック「リストア」
[4] [2]のwatashinodb.backup ファイルを指定して[リストア]実行
[5] 下記のメッセージを受け取る；

> C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "XXX" --dbname "YYY" --no-password  --verbose "C:\Users\ZZZ\Documents\watashinodb.backup"
> pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header
> プロセスは、1 のリターンコードを返しました。

環境／インストール済みパッケージ：
■端末A：
*PostgreSQL：9.6.18

pgAdmin3：1.2.22

pgAdminのpg_dump.exe：9.6.xx*
■端末B：
*PostgreSQL：9.6.18

pgAdmin3：1.2.22  (Nov 10 2016, rev:REL-1_22_1-11-g63077d9)

pgAdminのpg_restore.exe：9.5.5*

【状況補足】
※元々、端末Bには PostgreSQL9.4.5 がインストールされていました。
メッセージはPostgreSQLのバージョン相違によるものと考えて、端末B から9.4.5アンインストール、Windows再起動を経て、9.6.20をインストール。
バージョン9.6.20においてリストアを実行しても、冒頭に挙げたエラーメッセージを受け取ります。
さらに端末Aに合わせるために、9.6.20アンインストール、Windows再起動を経て、9.6.18 をインストールして現在に至ります。
（どのバージョンにおいてもpgAdmin 上での右クリックから「リストア」を実行した結果は、冒頭に挙げたメッセージの返却に終わります）

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header」で検索すると「https://qiita.com/jtakahashi64/items/410aae45df2296e6719b」がヒットしました。「https://help.heroku.com/YNH1ZJUS/why-am-i-getting-pg_restore-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-error-with-pg_restore」がリンクされていました。原因としてpg_restoreのバージョン違いが関係しているようにに読めます。見つけただけで何も確認していませんが参考になればと思いコメントします。

Comment: @akiraejiri 確認しました。原因は参照先の記事のものであると考えているのですが、解決策がわかりません。

Comment: pg_restoreのバージョンの問題のようですが、pg_restore --versionは実行可能ですか？可能ならバージョンを調べて「質問」に追記してください。

Comment: @akiraejiri 追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[5]のメッセージを見るとpgAdmin3のインストール先のpg_restore.exeが実行されています。

pgAdmin3のメニュー「ファイル」－「オプション」のBinaryPathsを開いて「PG binパス」をインストールしたPostgeSQLのbinパスに変更したら上手くいかないでしょうか？

Comment: こちらの方法を応用して、リストアができるようになりました。インストールしたPostgreSQLのbinフォルダには端末Aのexeを配置

Answer (score 0):

以下のページによると
https://help.heroku.com/YNH1ZJUS/why-am-i-getting-pg_restore-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-error-with-pg_restore

pg_restoreを (10.3, 9.6.8, 9.5.12, 9.4.17, and 9.3.22).以上のバージョンに上げる必要がありそうです。

お使いのpg_restore.exeはバージョンが9.5.5ですのでバージョンアップが必要そうです。

pg_restore.exeを単体でバージョンを上げる方法はわかりません。

PostgreSQLの各バージョンに対応するpg_restoreのバージョンを調べるのが本筋かもしれませんが、
一時的に最新の10や13のPostgreSQLをインストールしてリストアが可能かを試してみてはいかがでしょうか？